# Oauth client verification google . How can i track my verification request

Tags: oauth, gmail-api, google-apps, google-oauth

I have submitted our oauth client id  for verification, its been a long time since i got reply from them.can someone help me about it.like how long does it take? and how to get approve  oauth client id? Is there anyway to contact API & Trust Team of google to seek help from them?.

Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for Google](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 2):

The following can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#requesting_verification)

> Most verification requests receive a response within 24 to 72 hours. When verification of your OAuth client is confirmed, your app is verified.

Unfortunately Google does not offer live support for their free products.  I know of no way to contact them.   Nor is their a way to track your request.